# Harmless complex function $i^z=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Firstly i've done, **$e^{(zlni)}=1$**  and   **$lni=\frac{i\pi z}{2}$**
but i couldn't go further and continue to solve that problem, it ask me to find solution set.

i thought it has 2 multi-variable parts, also can't figure out where and when it is a multi-variable.

Edit: professor said that "$z=\frac{4m}{1+4n}$ $m,n \in \Bbb Z$". How is that possible?

Comment: use the definition of $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ for complex $z$ probably.

Comment: You should start here:$$i=e^{\pi i/2},\quad1=e^0$$And adjust for period.

Comment: FYI, the object $$i^z$$ is simply undefined for general complex values of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you know that $e^w=1$ if and only if $w=n\cdot 2\pi i $ for some $n\in\mathbb Z$.

So you need to find the $z$ such that $z\operatorname{Log} i = n\cdot 2\pi i$.

Comment: is that a principal log? if it is then z answers for z=4n

Comment: @DoubleOreo: Yes, that is the principal logarithm -- whether that is the right thing to do depends on how you interpret "$i^z$" in the question.